# How to redirect to new route when click on anchor tag using JS?

Tags: javascript

I have an anchor tag in an `EJs file-

```
 <a href="/posts/" tile>Read More</a>
```

And a route in `app.js` file-

```
app.get('/posts/:userId', function (request6, response6) {
  var resquestedTitle = _.lowerCase(request6.params.userId);
  // For each postObject(elements)inside posts array we check the if condition
  posts.forEach(function (elements) {
    // Inside {} we have access to individual postObjects inside posts array
    // From the compose
    var storedTitle = _.lowerCase(elements.tile);
    // Checking for each postObject whether if storedTitle matches the requested title
    if (resquestedTitle === storedTitle) {
      // When the requestedTitle matches the storedTitle(tile of postObject), only then we render the post page
      // Rendering post.ejs using respose6.render method, post is the name of page we want to render

      response6.render('post', {
        // Inside {} we pass in JavaScript objects with key value pair
        // actualPosts and elements.tile are key value pair

        actualPosts: elements.tile,
        postContent: elements.bodytext,
        id: request6.params.userId,
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Match Not Found' + resquestedTitle);
    }
  });
});
```

Here is the anchor tag on which click I want to redirect to some route i.e /posts/anything.

```
<a href="/posts/<%=tile%>">Read More</a>
```

Comment: You keep writing `tile`. Should that be _`title`_ instead?